# Is there a way to get info about parent UI element from android touch event?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is there a library that I can integrate with my app, which can track all touch events in my app, and tell me which UI element was touched with which touch event.
If not, looking at the android documentation for touch event, it only gives a motion event which gives information about x,y coordinates of the touch. Is there a way to get the parent UI element which a touch event touched?

Comment: If you have the actual `View` on which the touch event triggered, then you can just use `view.getParent()`

Comment: I did this, but since I am loading the image for the imageview from a server, so the getParent() keeps giving me a new id every time the activity is loaded.